# JasperReports Prints Empty PDF

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jasper-reports

I'm trying to generate a pdf file from data in a database using JasperReports with a java servlet. The first time I generated a pdf file successfully with data in database. Then I made some changes in my database table and recreated `jrxml` file and created a `jasper` file using that `jrxml` file. But now when I am trying to generate a pdf, the pdf file is always empty.

Code in my Servlet

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
try {

    HttpSession hs = request.getSession();
    String id = (String) hs.getAttribute("id");

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exam", "root", "pass");
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery 
            ("SELECT marks, date_time FROM result where sub_id = 1  and user_id = 3");

    ServletOutputStream set = response.getOutputStream();
    InputStream re = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("./results.jasper");
    JRResultSetDataSource resultSetDataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(resultSet);
    JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(re,set, new HashMap(), resultSetDataSource);

} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: @AndrewThompson

`NullPointerException` with below line

`JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(re,set, new HashMap(), resultSetDataSource);`

Comment: OK.. so which one of `re`, `set` or `resultSetDataSource` is `null`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I found the error. My original `.jasper` file name is `Results.jasper`. but in my code i gave it as `results.jasper`. I corrected it. Now there are no any errors print on stack trace. but when i run the servlet, pdf file is not generated.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Now i have created new project and write a servlet and run that project. then pdf file is generated. so again i run my previous project. now it is working without errors. it also generated a pdf file.

Comment: OK.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)  I added my advice re. Stack traces as an answer (I figured it would help solve the problem, one way or another).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change every `catch` to

```
...
} catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

That will provide details of what is going wrong, and where.